# Device tree create device at root

Tags: driver, u-boot, device-tree

I'm writing a UBoot driver for bitbanged NAND and need to add it to the device tree.
Because this device is not on any bus and only references GPIO pins, I want to put it directly at the device tree root (like it's done for [`gpio-leds`](https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/blob/master/arch/mips/dts/huawei%2Chg556a.dts)):

```
/ {
    nand {
        status = "ok";
        compatible = "onfi,bitbang-nand";
        pinctrl-0 = <&nand_pins>;
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        nand-bus-width = <8>;
        data-gpios = <&gpio 40 0>,
        <&gpio 41 0>,
        <&gpio 42 0>,
        <&gpio 43 0>,
        <&gpio 44 0>,
        <&gpio 45 0>,
        <&gpio 46 0>,
        <&gpio 47 0>;
        ale-gpios = <&gpio 38 0>;
        cle-gpios = <&gpio 39 0>;
        nre-gpios = <&gpio 36 0>;
        nwe-gpios = <&gpio 35 0>;
        nce-gpios = <&gpio 44 0>;
        nwp-gpios = <&gpio 44 0>;
        rdy-gpios = <&gpio 47 0>;
    };
};
```

When the device is declared as such, UBoot does not recognize the device, and it's not even present in device tree node binding log. When I add a subnode to the device, UBoot recognizes `nand` as a device:

```
/ {
    nand {
        compatible = "onfi,bitbang-nand";
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <1>;
        pinctrl-0 = <&nand_pins>;
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        nand@0 {
            status = "ok";
            nand-bus-width = <8>;
            data-gpios = <&gpio 40 0>,
            <&gpio 41 0>,
            <&gpio 42 0>,
            <&gpio 43 0>,
            <&gpio 44 0>,
            <&gpio 45 0>,
            <&gpio 46 0>,
            <&gpio 47 0>;
            ale-gpios = <&gpio 38 0>;
            cle-gpios = <&gpio 39 0>;
            nre-gpios = <&gpio 36 0>;
            nwe-gpios = <&gpio 35 0>;
            nce-gpios = <&gpio 44 0>;
            nwp-gpios = <&gpio 44 0>;
            rdy-gpios = <&gpio 47 0>;
        };
    };
};
```

Why the first example is not considered a device and the second one is? I couldn't find anything relevant in the [specification](https://devicetree-specification.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: If you add an address 'nand@0' and a reg property in your first example does that solve your problem?

Comment: What driver matches this compatible string?  Perhaps it's the driver that expects/requires the subnode? I.E. the driver considers the configuration to be incomplete because of a missing subnode, and therefore doesn't install any device.     BTW you reference an outdated/undated version of the DT spec.  There's a v0.4-rc1 out there dated 30 Nov 2021.

Comment: @Xypron yes, it does (as described in the question). But the question is why the first example not recognized as a device?

Comment: @sawdust It's the driver I'm writing. At this point, it just prints hello when the device is probed. However, the problem is not with the driver, because, as the UBoot log shows, a device class instance is not created for the node for the first example. For the second one device is created and driver probing kicks in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a silly mistake. According to the specification, the right `status` value is `okay`, not `ok`. So, the node `nand` was read by `dm_scan_fdt_node` in `drivers/core/root.c` and discarded as disabled. Second version was found because absent `status` field is equivalent to the enabled device.